# How to do a very simple do until loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do a very simple macro in Google Sheets.

Anyway, I have a bunch of cells containing the `rand()` function and I just need to recalculate the sheet a bunch of times (1000?, 100,000? I don't know) until a vast set of criteria are met.

A very, very, very stripped down version of what I want to do is below. If I knew what I was doing, it would calculate a random number in A1, it would then go through the do-while loop and only plug 'This is a completely arbitrary command' into A2 if A1 < .001.

```
function ThisDoesNotWork() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').setFormula('=rand()');
  do { 
    spreadsheet.getRange('a2').setValue('All I really want Sheets to do is recalculate!');
  }while ( spreadsheet.getRange('A1') < .001 );
};
```

It does nothing of the sort. I run it and it plugs 'All I really want Sheets to do is recalculate!' into A2 no matter what the value in A1 is.

Answer (score 0):

First, the terms used in Google Sheets / Google Apps Script / JavaScript are a bit different than in Excel / VBA.

The code included in the question is a function, also referred as a script, not a macro. To learn the basics about using Google Apps Script with Google Sheets read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and to learn about macros in Google Sheets, read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros.

Second, what you are trying to do, should not be done in Google Sheets. One of the reasons is that the spreasheet will be updated until the script finish. You might use `SpreasheetApp.flush()` to force the update of the spreadsheet at certain point of the script execution but I suggest to avoid playing with this until you have a better understading of how Google Sheets, Google Apps Script and JavaScript works together.

To learn about loops, instead try this first:

```
function myLoopFunction(){
   let n = 0;
   do{
     console.log(n);
   } while( ++n < 10)
}
```

The above code includes only JavaScript. It will log the value of `n` until the whil condition is meet.

`++` will increment the value of `n` before comparing it with `10`.

Contrary to what might happen with Excel / VBA that run using only the resources of your computer, Google Sheets / Google Apps Scripts run using the resources of your computer and Google servers. Google have set quotas (limits). I.E. if you using a consumer account, the maximum execution time scripts is 6 minutes. For scripts called from simple triggers and custom function the execution limit is 30 seconds. Because of this it's better to not play with loops using random iterations.

Answer (score -1):

You can try script editor.

In sheets , open the script editor from Tools -> Script editor

More details you can go through...
https://sites.google.com/a/unifiedlearning.co.uk/scripting/starting-out/looping

For learning, to get started with google's script
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions. For better or worse, the first page you linked me to was precisely the one that I used to generate the code that doesn't work! The logic is simple. I'm just a professor who never really learned how to code in grad school and now I just need one tiny little program.